# merge consecutive skips like css

Tags: spacing

I have a series of figure-like paragraphs generated by a command of mine, and would like to have a minimum amount of vertical space above and below these figure-like paragraphs, but I don't want the double the space when two of them follow eachother.

Using css, I would use the following code, since CSS merges two consecutive margins and leaves only a space equivalent to the largest :

```
.myclass { margin-top: 1cm; margin-bottom: 1cm; }
```

I can achieve the result I want (the same space above the first `\mycommand`, between the two `\mycommand`, and after the second `\mycommand`) using the following LaTeX code, but I would like to avoid the \vskip 1cm that I manually added after the second `\mycommand` :

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\def\mycommand{
  \bgroup
  \vskip 1cm
  \rule{10cm}{2cm}
  \par
  \egroup
}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\mycommand
\mycommand
\vskip 1cm
\lipsum[2]
\lipsum[3]
\end{document}
```

[image: Manually added space]

If I choose the option to redefine `\mycommand` like this, then I have twice the space between the first `\mycommand` and the second :

```
\def\mycommand{
  \bgroup
  \vskip 1cm
  \rule{10cm}{2cm}
  \par
  \vskip 1cm
  \egroup
}
```

[image: Double space]

I have tried fiddling with TeX's glues (1cm minus 1cm for example), but didn't get the result I want.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

LaTeX provides `\addvspace{<len>}` that adds vertical space only if needed, up to `<len>`. This seems to be what you're after:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}% http://ctan.org/pkg/lipsum
\def\mycommand{
  \bgroup
  \addvspace{1cm}
  \rule{10cm}{2cm}
  \par
  \addvspace{1cm}
  \egroup
}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\mycommand
\mycommand
\lipsum[2]
\lipsum[3]
\end{document}
```

One area where `\addvspace` is commonly used is in ToC-entries (like the "List of Figures"/LoF) to denote the gap between chapter entries (in `book` and `report` document classes). For example, if some chapter has no figures, you don't want an additional (or larger) gap between the LoF entries. Here is an extract from the `\chapter` command in [`book.cls`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/unpacked/book.cls):

```
\addtocontents{lof}{\protect\addvspace{10\p@}}%
\addtocontents{lot}{\protect\addvspace{10\p@}}%
```

that adds `10pt`.