# Add vertical space only if no vertical space was added previously

Tags: spacing

Perhaps this is the silliest of all the questions, but, let’s suppose that there are two custom commands:

```
\newcommand{\cmdA}[1]{
    #1
    \vspace{1cm}
}

\newcommand{\cmdB}[1]{
    \vspace{1cm}     % should be some sort of intelligent space
    #1
}
```

Now, in the real latex world, if I use:

```
\cmdA{Test text A}

\cmdB{Test text B}
```

The output will be:

Test text A

-------------- 2cm in here

Test text B

With 2cm in between. Instead, I want 1cm in between, yet, in the case of:

```
\cmdA{Test text A}

In the middle text

\cmdB{Test text B}
```

The output should be:

Test text A

-------------- 1cm in here

In the middle text

-------------- 1cm in here

Test text B

Separated by 1cm each. This is the trivial example, using silly custom commands. But I wonder if there is some sort of a generic solution.

Comment: Welcome to Tex.SX. I think `\addvspace` does what you seek.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Merge consecutive skips like CSS](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/60972/5764)